# How can I use RedisInsight to connect to a MemoryDb instance in AWS?

Tags: redis, amazon-memory-db, redisinsights

Does anyone have a simple set of instructions on how to authenticate with MemoryDb using a Redis Data Management Client? This probably applies to clients beyond RedisInsight

I have configured a MemoryDB cluster in AWS on a VPC that I have access to. I have created a MemoryDb user that seems to have universal access with a username and password. I also have an IAM role that appears to have programmatic access to MemoryDb with an attached user profile. The ONLY AWS documentation I can find for authenticating with a MemoryDb instance is via programmatic access with IAM Roles: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/auth-iam.html

No matter whether I use the MemoryDb user or attempt to extrapolate from the programmatic access guide, I always receive an error about the username or password being incorrect. I'm sure the Database is reachable because we can Telnet to the cluster endpoint and it gave connection timeout errors before we added its VPC to our VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested RedisInsight Version 2.32.0 on Windows and was able to connect to Redis MemoryDB on AWS. If TLS is enabled on AWS, ensure that it is checked in the RedisInsight UI too :)

Reference: https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/752